# Conditional rendering in React unmounting siblings

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was reading [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) article regarding React's Reconciliation strategy.

I've a `Parent` component which has 2 child components  - `Child1`, and `Child2`. Where the `Child2` component is conditionally rendered.

```
render() {
    const firstChild = <Child1 key="child-1"/>;
    const secondChild = this.props.someVariable ? 
        <Child2 key="child-2" /> : 
        <OtherChild key="child-other" />;
    const children = [firstChild, secondChild];
    return (
        <Parent>
            {firstChild}
            {secondChild}
        </Parent> 
    );
}
```

Now what I see is that as `<Child2>` and  `OtherChild` are 2 different types of component, `Child2` will be unmounted to get `OtherChild` mounted. And `componentWillUnmount` of `Child2` will be called (given that `Child2` is currently mounted)

This is fine, and I understand this. But I also see `componentWillUnmount` of `Child1` getting called.

Is this expected? (Note that I'm passing hardcoded-keys as of now so there's no chance of components getting unmounted because of a different key)

So my question is that **will unmounting of a sibling force unmounting of another sibling?** (given that it's the second sibling that's unmounted and it's causing unmounting of the first sibling)

I don't think so this should be the case. Can anyone point out if my observation here is correct or I'm missing something here?

Comment: it doesn't have to do with siblings, you just pass those 2 components as children of `Parent` component, and `componentWillUnmount` gets called in each of them before it renders those

Comment: But I'm seeing `Child1` getting unmounted, and then remounted. Also when I make the component type of `secondChild` same, this problem goes away. I'll edit my question to include this observation also.

Comment: try to put <Child1 /> directly in jsx code, instead of saving it into firstChild.

Comment: @SorcererApprentice can you please explain how that will help? Originally there's a function call to get a component for `firstChild`

Comment: Ouch! In this case it's isn't helpful at all.